# ImportError: No module named 'zope.interface'

Tags: transactions, pip, pyramid, python-3.5, zope.interface

On Mac:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1/scripts/initializedb.py", line 3, in <module>
    import transaction
  File "/Users/denmojo/code/project1/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/transaction/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from transaction._transaction import Transaction
  File "/Users/denmojocode/project1/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py", line 20, in <module>
    from zope.interface import implementer
ImportError: No module named 'zope.interface'
```

Cannot figure out why it is there, but not importing the module.

```
Using /Users/denmojo/code/project1/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zope.interface-4.3.2-py3.5-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
```

Comment: This error can happen if you are mixing `easy_install` and `pip`. Please use one or the other (preferably `pip`).

Answer (score 5):

Tried:

```
pip uninstall transaction
pip uninstall zope.interface
pip install transaction
pip install zope.interface
```

Resolved the issue. I suppose my previous virtualenv setups or out-of-order pip installs caused something to go wrong with `zope.interface-4.3.2-py3.5-macosx-10.6-intel.egg`

Comment: Solved my issue too